# Select distinct on one col and everything else

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying the following but it fails... I want everything but only if distinct name:

so, if i have

```
NAME    A  B  C  D
-------------------
john    5  6  6  7
jack    5  3  2  4
paul    5  7  9  2
john    4  2  3  4
```

I only want the first three lines

```
select distinct name, * from items order by NAME, D
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What should the result set be for john?

Comment: what is the criteria to avoid a record , if there are duplicate names?

Comment: Which of the values from a,b,c,d should be displayed for John?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) instead:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM items a
     INNER JOIN ( SELECT MIN(id) id
                  FROM items
                  GROUP BY name
                ) b
                ON a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.name;
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eaaf/1)

Comment: output doesnot tally name A B C D
jack 5 3 2 4
john 9 8 9 11
paul 5 7 9 2

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care which of the values are picked in case of a duplicate name:

```
select name,
       min(a),
       min(b),
       min(c),
       min(d)
from items
group by name
order by name;
```

Note that with this solution the values for a,b,c,d do not necessarily come from the same row!

Answer (score 2):

**Sample Input:**

```
Name    A   B   C   D
john    5   6   6   7
jack    5   3   2   4
paul    5   7   9   2
john    4   2   3   4
john    5   6   6   7
```

**Query**

```
SELECT Name,Max(A) AS A,MAX(B) AS B,MAX(C) AS C,MAX(D) AS D
FROM <your table>
GROUP BY Name
```

**Expected Output**

```
Name    A   B   C   D
jack    5   3   2   4
john    5   6   6   7
paul    5   7   9   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select distinct name,A,B,C,D from items group by name order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

This will select any one record if you have  duplicate names

```
   select slno,name,A,B,C,D
   from           
   ( SELECT  @i:=@i+1 AS slno,t.*
     FROM items t ,(SELECT @i:=0) r )a
   group  by    name  
   having slno=min(slno)
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd3fe/1)